# Selenium [DEPRECATION] :profile is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options#profile= instead

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I have a testing bot on GNU/Linux which enters some emails to some form and submits them. It's not integrated with Rails.

My bot looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
%w(capybara/dsl selenium-webdriver).each(&method(:require))

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path = '/opt/firefox-developer-edition/firefox'

Capybara.register_driver(:default_profile) do |a|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(a, browser: :firefox, profile: 'default')
end

Capybara.default_driver = :default_profile
Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(640, 720)

emails = %w(
    something1@someone.me
    something2@someone.me
    something3@someone.me
    something4@someone.me
    something5@someone.me
    something6@someone.me
    something7@someone.me
)

names = %W(Sourav SouravGoswami #{"Sourav Goswami"})

n = emails.length
time, len, dsl = Time.now, n.to_s.length, Class.new.extend(Capybara::DSL)

emails.each.with_index do |email, i|
        name = names.rotate![0]

        elap = Time.now - time
        rem = n.*(elap).fdiv(i + 1).-(elap)
        print "\e[2K#{sprintf("%0#{len}d", i)} / #{n} | Elapsed: #{elap.round(1)} s | Remaining: #{rem.round(1)} s\r"

        dsl.visit('https://somewebsite.net')
        dsl.find('#name').set(name)
        dsl.find('#email').set(email)
        dsl.find('#submit').click
end
```

But every time I run it, with fully updated selenium webdriver, I get these warnings:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:54: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/driver.rb:31: warning: The called method `new' is defined here
2020-09-24 16:13:14 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] :profile is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options#profile= instead.
```

So I have considered using:

```
c = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new
c.profile = 'default'
```

But this doesn't open up firefox in the default profile, and it also doesn't resize the window.

I can't find a good documentation documenting `Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options#profile`.

So how do I get rid of this error (except using -W0 ruby flags)?

Comment: If you using capybara, then add capybara tag. Other tags are not important.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this folder

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
```

and then you find default folder with some name .default, copy that file and append that name with the given path above

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\zxbjl3ls.default
```

Then write the following code

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new('C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\zxbjl3ls.default')

driver=Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox,:profile => profile
```

**Update:**

```
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new(ENV['APPDATA'] + '\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\Normal')
```

Comment: While you can get the profile in `about:support` page, it's most likely located in the ~/.mozilla directory. But the problem is, I can't hard code it. There's no point to hard code the path to remove the deprecation warning. If I really need to hard code, I am good with the deprecation warning!

Comment: Actually I am not using Windows, and my environment doesn't have anything associated with 'APPDATA', it just returns nil... :( Unfortunately ... In other words, this might work on Windows, but on my GNU/Linux system, it's actually doing nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Because the way you're handling the webdriver initialization is deprecated with current Selenium Webdriver. I would suggest taking a look at this snippet from Capybara repo as the reference :

https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/registrations/drivers.rb#L11

Basically, the `:profile` is deprecated and instead parsing it into your driver initialization as `Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(a, browser: :firefox, profile: 'default')`, you need to build up the Browser Options as the logs suggestion:

`Option 1: Using customize profile`

```
CAPYBARA_WINDOW_SIZE = [640, 720].freeze
ff_profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new.tap do |profile| 
# Use this if you want to customize your Firefox profile
# For example:
   profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2
....
....
end

ff_options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new(profile: ff_profile)

ff_options.add_argument('-headless') 
ff_options.add_argument("window-size=#{CAPYBARA_WINDOW_SIZE.join(',')}"

Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :firefox, options: ff_options)
```

`Option 2: Using default profile`

```
CAPYBARA_WINDOW_SIZE = [640, 720].freeze

ff_options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new

ff_options.add_argument('-headless') 
ff_options.add_argument("window-size=#{CAPYBARA_WINDOW_SIZE.join(',')}"

options[:options] = ff_options

Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :firefox, options: ff_options)
```